# Web server (on 1 machine) serving files from another machine EC2

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, amazon-ec2, web-server

I am trying to setup the following configuration (or at least this is what I've got in my mind).

1. EC2 instance running the web server (Nginx or Apache)
2. EC2 instance where the actual site files are located. (an EBS volume is attached to it)
3. Backup EC2 instance, in case of failure of the 1st instance, it will be the main server.

I just want to know whether my idea is OK, or even if it is possible, it is totally bad, and disk performance will be awful (considering what people say about EBS performance in general without additional layers of complexity).

If I'm wrong from the start, then what would you suggest. I know that I can serve the site from one server, and just have the exact backup on the second server, but I don't want to sync the changes between them (just don't have the experience). Of course if it's much better, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to Put Web server behind Load Balancer..

1. Load Balancer ( Haproxy or Nginx )
2. Web1 and Web2  ( Behind Haproxy)
3. EBS i/o is slow , you can try NFS or GlusterFS.